# Xamarin adding NuGet package

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, nuget-package, sqlite-net

I want to add NuGet package in my Xamarin Forms project to use SQLite-Net package. Following the guideline from  [Xamarin web site](http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/xamarin-forms/working-with/databases/), I click on Add NuGet Packages in my XamarinForms.iOS. It processes and error ConnectFailure (connection timed out).

I have been trying this from last two days and I am getting same error. How can I add SQLite-net library to my project?

It is a type of PCL library Xamarin Forms project.

Comment: do you have the latest version of the NuGet manager installed?  Are you using a proxy or firewall that would prevent you from accessing nuget.org?

Comment: Have you tried to install it via the PacketManager-Console? And be sure (as sad before) that you have the latest version of NuGet manager

Comment: If you have ReSharper installed it can also cause some issues with nuget packages and xamarin. If you disable it and try again it normally sorts it out

Comment: I am using Xamarin Studio and i guess i don't need to install NuGet manager. Xamarin has built in support for NuGet. It could be proxy or firewall preventing installation.

Comment: Something is blocking Xamarin Studio. I would run some networking tests, such as trying to telnet to www.nuget.org on port 443 and port 80. Do you have a proxy? Can you connect to the update server (i.e. check for updates does not return an error)? If you open the addin manager can you see any addins from the gallery?

Comment: Other network it worked!!!!

Comment: @mobiletest are you able add any other packages other than SqlLite package ?

Comment: Yes. I guess i had network issue which was blocking Xamarin studio. When i connected to a different network it worked.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a problem with the latest Nuget manager.
If you remove it then go to nugets website and install the v3.3 one you should not have any more problems.